# Android Error inflating class SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

I am working on an App right now that uses 3 tabs with a fragment in each and I am trying to implement SwipeRefreshLayout in each of these fragments. I believe that I have created this correctly, but I continue to get the errors:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class SwipeRefreshLayout
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.SwipeRefreshLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ryan.brooks.fropllc.frop.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ryan.brooks.fropllc.frop.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at com.ryan.brooks.fropllc.frop.app.whatsGoingOnFragment.onCreateView(whatsGoingOnFragment.java:23)
```

Now I have absolutely no idea what is causing this. If anybody could help me that would be tremendously appreciated.

Here is my fragment layout where I am implementing the SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
<SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_whats_going_on">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#343434"></ScrollView>

</SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And here is my fragment class where I am calling the SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
public class WhatsGoingOnFragment extends Fragment {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whats_going_on_fragment, container, false);

        // Retrieve the SwipeRefreshLayout and ListView instances
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_whats_going_on);

        // Set the color scheme of the SwipeRefreshLayout by providing 4 color resource ids
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(
                android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Both the layouts and class structure are the exact same for all 3 fragments just with id name changes. I really have no clue what is going wrong here. Again any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I might be way off the mark here but can you try `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` in xml file instead?

Comment: @hypd09 you were completely correct!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to use a full package name for `SwipeRefreshLayout`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ryan.brooks.fropllc.frop.app.whatsGoingOnFragment"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_whats_going_on">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#343434"></ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, such a simple mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm using ActionbarSherlock and i can't use SwipeRefreshLayout in the xml (i can import it ok and use it un code) any idea ?

Comment: Great Tiny resolution!